# Getting Google OAuth Refresh Token in a GAE Python App

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I am using the code below to get the Google refresh token by exchanging the oauth code.

```
access_token_uri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
redirect_uri = selfURL + "oauth2callback?step=token"

params = urllib.urlencode({
       #'access_token_uri': access_token_uri,
        'code': code,
        'client_id': self.client_id,
        'client_secret': self.client_secret,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
    })
headers={'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Content-length':len(params),'Host':'accounts.google.com'}
response = urlfetch.fetch(
                              url=access_token_uri,
                              payload=params,
                              method='POST',
                              headers=headers,
                              allow_truncated=False,
                              follow_redirects=True,
                              deadline=100)
```

However it is sending a invalid request response

> {
>     "error" : "invalid_request"
>   }

Any help?